# Enum has lesses accessability than property Outcome1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

```
public class SecretNumber
{
    //Construktor
    public SecretNumber()
    {
        Initialize();
        _previousGuesses = new List<int>();
    }

    //Constant
    public const int MaxNumberOfGuesses = 7;

    //Field
    private int _number;
    private List<int> _previousGuesses;

    //Property
    public bool CanMakeGuess
    {
        get;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get;
    }

    public int? Number
    {
        public get;
    }

    //Lite oklart hur man ska göra när fälten är autoimplementerade
    public Outcome Outcome1
    {
        get
        {
            return Outcome1;
        }
        private set
        {
            Outcome1 = value;
        }
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<int> PreviousGuesses
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    //Methods
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        _number = random.Next(1, 100);

        _previousGuesses.Clear();

        Outcome1 = Outcome.Indefinite;
    }

    private Outcome MakeGuess(int guess)
    {
        if (Number > 1 && Number < 100)
        {
            if (PreviousGuesses.Contains(guess))
            {
                return Outcome.PreviousGuess;
            }
            else if (PreviousGuesses.Count >= MaxNumberOfGuesses)
            {
                return Outcome.NoMoreGuesses;
            }
            if (Number == guess)
            {
                return Outcome.Correct;
            }
            else if (Number < guess)
            {
                return Outcome.High;
            }
     //       else if (Number > guess)
       //     {
                return Outcome.Low;
         //   }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Måste vara inom intervallet 1-100");
        }
    }

    //Enumerator
    enum Outcome
    {
        Indefinite,
        Low,
        High,
        Correct,
        NoMoreGuesses,
        PreviousGuess
    }
}
```

I get the errormessage that my enum Secret number has lesses accessability than the property Outcome1, but I have no idea why.

The property is called Outcome1 because otherwise the names were mixed up in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your enum has `private` visibility as you haven't given it an explicit visibility, and it's nested within your `SecretNumber` class.

You can't use a type as a parameter or return type of a member that's exposed publicly<sup>1</sup> when that type isn't also public - otherwise the caller wouldn't know what to do with it.

You can just make it public:

```
public enum Outcome
```

---

<sup>1</sup> That's not *quite* the same as "of a public member". For example, a `public` (non-overriding) method in an `internal` type can refer to other internal members as parameters - because the method could still only be called by another type which knew about the "containing" `internal` type anyway.

Comment: So it should be outside the class? Thanks.

Comment: @HerrNilsson: It *could* be outside the class, but you'd still then need to make it public. It's just that the default for a nested type is `private` instead of `internal`. Neither is the same as `public`.

Comment: @HerrNilsson, If usage of the enumeration is in this class only then keep it in the scope of same class..

Answer (score 1):

You have a package-visible `enum` and a `public` property that returns it. You should make `Outcome1` private or package-visible, or make your `enum` public. You could also move the `enum` out of your class, if it makes sense in the broader context. Which option is right is your design decision.

P.S. The comment calls your `enum` an *Enumerator*, which is not a correct name for an enumerated type.

Answer (score 1):

The default accessor (when one is not explicitly provided) is `private` when within a class.

```
public enum Outcome
{
    Indefinite,
    Low,
    High,
    Correct,
    NoMoreGuesses,
    PreviousGuess
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your enum is not public. Other classes that will use SecretNumber won't be able to use the enum.